# how to create form dynamically with in form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have created an extension using formbuilder. Now I have used it in my view.
My view looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("addDataInd", "CustInformations", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <fieldset class="field">
    <legend>Addresses</legend>
      <table>
        <tr>                            
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.addresses) 
        </tr>
      </table>           
  </fieldset> 
}
```

where

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.addresses)
```

calls my EditorTemplate which looks like:

```
<td>
@Html.hSearch("txtSearch", "", "lblsrch", "Search Text: ", "Search", "Fetch", "LookUp", new { script = "Select Aid, FullAreaName from fGetAreaTB()" }, null)
</td>
```

When i run the program the page looks like

[image]

i used fire bug to know the error. All I found was that, the code generated for the first
upper image (i.e. for permanent address) it doesn't create a form, but for other two it creates a form. So when I click the first search button, it doesn't work but when i click the second and third button it works well.

I just want when i run the program all the button must be in form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot nest HTML forms. For this reason you will have to use multiple forms and put them inside the template. Like this:

```
<fieldset class="field">
    <legend>Addresses</legend>
    <table>
        <tr>                            
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.addresses) 
        </tr>
    </table>           
</fieldset>
```

and inside the editor template:

```
@model Address
<td>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("addDataInd", "CustInformations", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.hSearch("txtSearch", "", "lblsrch", "Search Text: ", "Search", "Fetch", "LookUp", new { script = "Select Aid, FullAreaName from fGetAreaTB()" }, null)
    }
</td>
```